# TYPO3 - Doctrine query NOT WHERE INNER JOIN if realurl path not exist for record

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-8.x, typo3-8.7.x

I'm rendering column uid, abc and name of table tx_abc_domain_model_abc ...

... but now I only want to render those records of which there has NOT been a realurl path been created.

So I guess I need a NOT WHERE INNER JOIN (https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Database/QueryBuilder/Index.html#join-innerjoin-rightjoin-and-leftjoin) for the two tables tx_abc_domain_model_abc and tx_realurl_uniqalias?

```
table: tx_abc_domain_model_abc
column: uid

table: tx_realurl_uniqalias
column: tablename = tx_abc_domain_model_abc
column: value_id
```

ActionController:

```
...
$statement = $queryBuilder  
    ->select('tx_abc_domain_model_abc.uid', 'tx_abc_domain_model_abc.abc', 'tx_abc_domain_model_abc.name')          
    ->from('tx_abc_domain_model_abc')
    ->join(
      'tx_abc_domain_model_abc',
      'tx_realurl_uniqalias'
      $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('tx_realurl_uniqalias.value_id', $queryBuilder->quoteIdentifier('tx_abc_domain_model_abc.uid'))
    )
   ->where(
      $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('tx_realurl_uniqalias.tablename', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter('tx_abc_domain_model_abc')),
        )                                       
    ->execute();
...
```

Is this correct? But how do the NOT WHERE?

Comment: in the SQL, it would be an *anti-join* pattern. That would be an outer join with a condition in the WHERE clause that checks for NULL in an expression that is guaranteed to be non-NULL if a match is found. For example, to get rows from `a` with no matching rows in `b` we could write something like this:  `FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON b.a_id = a.id WHERE b.a_id IS NULL`.  (note that a_id on a matching row is guaranteed to be non-NULL by the equality comparison)  This could also be expressed as a not exists predicate e.g. `FROM a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE b.a_id = a.id)`

Comment: Thanks for the information. By any chance ... could you also provide an example reflecting the above?

Comment: I can't really provide an example... I don't know the typo3 syntax for an antijoin or a `NOT EXISTS (crsq)`. I suspect typo3 is similar to other ORMs in that the documentation and examples do not acknowledge that an antijoin operation is possibly something we might want to do. (My SQL constructs were left in a comment, since this was asking about typo3.)  My question would be along the lines, how do I get typo3 to emit and execute an antijoin like this: `SELECT a.foo FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON b.a_id = a.id WHERE b.a_id IS NULL`

Answer (score 1):

You can do the "NOT" with "->neq" :

```
->neq($fieldName, $value)
```

So with your example :

```
$queryBuilder->expr()->neq('tx_realurl_uniqalias.tablename', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter('tx_abc_domain_model_abc'))
```

You can read it here : https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/latest/ApiOverview/Database/ExpressionBuilder/Index.html#comparisons